# In Vimium, make opening in new tab default with `f` key

Tags: google-chrome-extension

In Vimium, pressing `f` makes links open in current tab, and pressing `F` (capital `f`) makes links open in new background tab. I want to reverse this mapping, but

```
map f F
map F f
```

doesn't work. Nor does specifying `noremap` instead of `map` work.

Comment: This question is a better fit for [su]. For certain, it doesn't belong in the "Chrome extension **development**" tag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mapping two keys to each other shouldn't do anything. You want:

```
map f LinkHints.activateModeToOpenInNewTab
map F LinkHints.activateMode
```

If it did anything, it would be an infinite loop, which is bad.

Also, if you start with `f` and enter the hint (ie `f S`) in uppercase, that will open it in a new tab. (I think if the last hint key is in uppercase it will be a new tab, but I'm not positive.

Comment: Pressing `SHIFT` will switch between opening in current vs. new tab.